# Некорректно отображается блок в карусели

Tags: css, jquery, html5, слайдер, slick.js

На основе макета, хочу создать карусель Testimonial. В качестве слайдера использую Slick. Для создания блока так же использую Bootstrap 4. Карусель работает, однако внешний вид блока ломается. Вместо горизонтального размещения текста и изображения (как на картинке), блоки располагаются вертикально друг другу.

[image: Ожидаемый результат]

[Ссылка на код](https://codepen.io/Skirtam/pen/MdMgez)

```
codepen.io/Skirtam/pen/MdMgez
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Slick** перебил ваш *.row*, дав ему *display:inline-block*, либо вложите ваши данные в еще один контейнер, либо укажите правило:

> .slick-slide .row { display: flex!important; }